# Implementing Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe

Tags: c++, math, pi

A teacher at school decided to give me as a challenge to find the 161th, 271st, 314th digits of Pi. After quite a bit of searching online I ended up with the thought that the Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe algorithm should be the best one for the case. I managed to understand the expression, but I am still confused about how the hell I should implement this. Should I just do this for k = 0 to whatever digit I need and add the results? I think this is what I should do, but after trying some implementations, I always get a 4... Something is wrong... May someone explain how to implement this?

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    double pi = 0.0;

    for(int k = n; true; ++k)
    {
        pi += (4 / (8 * k + 1) - 2 / (8 * k + 4) - 1 / (8 * k + 5) - 1 / (8 * k + 6)) / pow(16, k);
        cout << pi << endl;
    }

    cout << pi << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, BBP generates hexadecimal digits; I'm guessing that you're looking for decimal digits. I think Plouffe (who actually invented the BBP formula; B & B jumped on his bandwagon) also developed a similar formula for decimal digits.

Comment: Based on [this](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/pi/HexPi%20%60.html) I think you need a lot more code in your solution.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues. First if you need to compute pi to many digits, you'll have to come up with a structure for holding the digits - a `double` will not suffice.

Second, integer division truncates to the integer below, which isn't what is intended in the mathematical formula.

Comment: I am with the impression that the formula can just get any digit from pi without needing to remember the previous ones. Then, why do you say I need something bigger than double to store?

Comment: IEEE double precision will hold about 16 digits of precision. After that you'll just be adding contributions that are too small to change the sum.

Comment: @frostblooded The problem is that you can't get more precision with a floating point variable. You need to perform the operations with numbers, but if you want to display the number you need to create a buffer, string, array... which keeps each number separately and then concatenates all of them.